# Vue - Use child component for add and update

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a pretty simple parent/child component. I want to use the child component in both ways - first for the operation to add a new entry and second for the operation to update an entity.

I have built this components: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bJdjyx Here I do not use props, I do sync the value from the parent to the child using custom events.

**add - Template:**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container grid-list-xl>
        <my-address
          :addresscompany.sync="addressCompany"
          :addressstreet.sync="addressStreet"
          ></my-address>
        <v-btn @click="submit">Submit</v-btn>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="address-template">
    <div>
      <v-text-field
        name="company"
        v-model="addressCompany"
        @change="updateCompany()">
        </v-text-field>
      <v-text-field
        name="street"
        v-model="addressStreet"
        @change="updateStreet()">
        </v-text-field>
    </div>
</script>
```

**add - Script:**

```
let addressComponent = {
  template: '#address-template',

  data() {
    return {
      addressCompany: '',
      addressStreet: '',
    }
  },

  methods: {
    updateCompany () {
      this.$emit('update:addresscompany', this.addressCompany);
    },
        updateStreet () {
      this.$emit('update:addressstreet', this.addressStreet);
    }
  }
};


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {'my-address' : addressComponent},

  data() {
    return {
      addressCompany: '',
      addressStreet: '',
    }
  },

  methods: {
    submit () {
      console.log('Company ' + this.addressCompany);
       console.log('Street ' + this.addressStreet);
    }
  }
})
```

But this template does not work for the edit case, because I need props to pass the value to the child. So I have come up with this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zXGLQG

**update - Template:**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container grid-list-xl>
        <my-address
          :addresscompany.sync="addressCompany"
          :addressstreet.sync="addressStreet"
          ></my-address>
        <v-btn @click="submit">Submit</v-btn>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>


<script type="text/x-template" id="address-template">
    <div>
      <v-text-field
        name="company"
         :value="addressCompany"
        @change="updateCompany()">
        </v-text-field>
      <v-text-field
        name="street"
         :value="addressStreet"
        @change="updateStreet()">
        </v-text-field>
    </div>
</script>
```

**update - Script:**

```
let addressComponent = {
  template: '#address-template',
  props: ['addressCompany', 'addressStreet'],

  data() {
    return {
    }
  },

  methods: {
    updateCompany () {
      this.$emit('update:addresscompany', this.addressCompany);
    },
        updateStreet () {
      this.$emit('update:addressstreet', this.addressStreet);
    }
  }
};


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {'my-address' : addressComponent},

  data() {
    return {
      addressCompany: 'Company',
      addressStreet: 'Street',
    }
  },

  methods: {
    submit () {
      console.log('Company ' + this.addressCompany);
       console.log('Street ' + this.addressStreet);
    }
  }
})
```

The main difference is, for the update case I do not use v-model on the child elements, because I can not directly change the props. But with :value being used, the update event is not triggered.

So what's the correct way of using that child component for add and update? There must be a standard Vue way before using Vuex for these purposes, is there any?

Thanks!

Comment: Your codepen just continuously refreshes for me

Comment: You can pass the edit data to the component via a prop, then use the custom event to update the data.

Comment: @TahaPaksu That's what I am doing in the second example? But as I use :value this does not work, because the custom event is not triggered.

Comment: use an event bus for the whole application?

Comment: https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860

Comment: DO NOT use an event bus for this, this is bad practice.

Comment: @DanielOrmeño - since when?

Comment: @DerekPollard. As per their documentation Parent / Child communications should happen through props and event bindings, using an event bus is suggested when communicating across sibling components, not between parent and child.

Answer (score 0):

I have often used the following pattern:

Create a component that is an abstraction of your entity, in the example below I used a `Person.vue` with `firstName` and `lastName` props.

```
Vue.component('Person' , {
   template: `
    <div>
      <input type="text"
             :value="firstName"
              @input="$emit('update:firstName', $event.target.value)"/>
      <input type="text"
              :value="lastName"
              @input="$emit('update:lastName', $event.target.value)"/>
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
  }
});
```

> The scope of this component is strictly limited to binding to a
>   `Person` object, reacting to its changes and updating the parent throw the `sync` event modifier.

Next, create a wrapping component that will Handle if the state of the actual object i.e. `Person.js`. Its child component `Person.vue` does not care if you are in Add or Edit "mode". This component is only responsible for reacting to the changes of the model.

This component should either load the `Person` Object form an API call or data store (Update mode), or create a new empty one i.e. `new Person()` (Add Mode).

A simple example is below, ideally the parent component (app in this case) would be split up so that you reduce the use of helper properties.

```js
function Person (firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}
Vue.component('Person' , {
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="text"
             :value="firstName"
              @input="$emit('update:firstName', $event.target.value)"/>
      <input type="text"
              :value="lastName"
              @input="$emit('update:lastName', $event.target.value)"/>
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <!-- Add mode, should be its own component -->
      <section v-if="promptAdd">
        <Person v-bind.sync="newPerson"/>
        <button type="button" @click="onAdded">Add</button>
      </section>
      <!-- Update mode, should be its own component -->
      <section v-else>
        <p>Users:</p>
        <div v-for="(person, index) in arr" :key="index">
          <Person v-bind.sync="person"/>
        </div>
        <button type="button"
                @click="addNew">Add New User</button>
      </section>
    </div>
  `,
  data: () => ({
    promptAdd: false,
    newPerson: undefined,
    arr: [
      new Person('Bob', 'Smith')
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    addNew() {
      this.newPerson = new Person();
      this.promptAdd = true;
    },
    onAdded () {
      this.arr.push({ ...this.newPerson });
      this.promptAdd = false;
      this.newPerson = undefined;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```